# Anonymous or lambda function inside method parameter

Tags: java, lambda

I saw following block of code in my teams codebase :

```
boolean value = fun(data->{
    data.setProperty();
    return data;
})
```

Above `fun` is a method which accepts objects of class called `Data`. However I have doubt:

I just saw `data` object only passed inside `fun` i.e there was no line of code like `Data data = new Data()` before above code snippet. Thus how above code snippet works ? It looks similar to lambda or anonymous functions. But I have never seen such code block in Java before. `data` object was present in whole .java file at only one place and that was above code block. I got curius how it's possible to use some object variable without declaring before.

Comment: Presumably `fun` passes in a `Data` object of _its_ choice, that _it_ creates or has a reference to.

Comment: `data` is passed to the function--we have no idea *where* that parameter is defined, declared, used, etc. What does `fun` do?

Comment: 'data' is a parameter whose type is not required. Imagine a world in which you have a normal method `void foo(String myParam)` , but the type can be omitted `void foo(myParam)` since it can be inferred. That's basically what's happening, but with different syntax.

Comment: @Michael Makes sense. That is what I was guessing. I am new grad and never saw such thing before.

Comment: @DaveNewton  ```fun``` accepts  ```Data``` and returns some boolean i.e. it's definition is ```boolean fun(Data)```.

Comment: @TheReal__Mike based on how it's called, `fun` accepts a _function_ that _takes_ a `Data` and returns a `Data`. Its signature is probably more something like `boolean fun(Function<Data, Data> function)` or `boolean fun(UnaryOperator<Data> operator)`. As Louis Wasserman said, `fun` determines how to get the `Data` input for the function.

Comment: Is the method perhaps overloaded?

Comment: @RobSpoor it's defined as boolean fun(UnaryOperator<Data> operator) in the codebase.

Comment: Your messages contradict one another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73804671/anonymous-or-lambda-function-inside-method-parameter#comment130322123_73804671

Comment: *`Thus how above code snippet works ?`* - What is the actual question - how to define a `UnaryOperator`? If you try to search, you'll find the answer withing a couple of minutes. Or just read through [*this tutorial*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)  provided by Oracle.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko  Yes, need to read about UnaryOperator. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you have for example

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface UnaryOperator<T> {
    void callMeWithData(T someData);
}

void fun(UnaryOperator<String> operator) {
    String theData = "hello";
    operator.callMeWithData(theData);
}

fun((data) -> {
   // prints "hello"
   System.out.println(data);
});
```

What you do here is to supply a function that acts like the `callMeWithData` method which also takes one parameter and returns nothing. Before Lambdas you would have to do

```
fun(new UnaryOperator<String>() {
    @Override
    public void callMeWithData(String someData) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
});
```

So the type of data is defined inside the single method in `UnaryOperator`, it's filled within `fn` and then received in your lambda as `data` (which is just an arbitrary name you can use here)